# Выборка данных из нескольких несвязанных таблиц в mysql

Tags: mysql, join

Помогите пожалуйста.
Есть 4 никак не связанные таблицы, в них содержаться одинаковые поля, необходимо выбрать данные следующим образом:
Вводится или название города или название отеля, и должны выбраться все данные по этому критерию, но в таблицах могут быть одинаковые названия отелей должна выбраться только одна запись по отелю и через join подставляться поля цены и название партнеров в одну строку.
Структура таблиц следующая:

```mysql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hotels` (
    `id` MEDIUMINT(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `city` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `hotel_name` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    `stars` FLOAT(2,1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `average` FLOAT(2,1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `latitude` DOUBLE(24,18) NOT NULL,
    `longitude` DOUBLE(24,18) NOT NULL,
    `address` TEXT(500) NOT NULL,
    `photo` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `hightlights` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    `description` TEXT(4000) NOT NULL,
    `rooms` SMALLINT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `url` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    `min_price` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `max_price` FLOAT NOT NULL,
    `partner_name` VARCHAR(30),
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
     KEY `city_id` (`city_id`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Расскажите лучше _смысл_ этих самых несвязанных таблиц. Какую из таблиц с одинаковым названием отеля нужно предпочесть?

Answer (score 0):

Никак не связанные между собой таблицы, имеющие одинаковые поля, должны представлять из себя **одну** таблицу. Точка.

При наличии одной таблицы выборка производится обычным образом.

Comment: Ну допустим, будет одна таблица и что само собой выборка пройдет?

Comment: Умников много развелось, острить в другом месте нужно.